# 'Not it is a servlet specified in web.xml' error in Netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, pojo

I have made a simple Servlet which is accessing a POJO object method in Netbeans.I have added Servlet details in web.xml also but on running the servlet class it is giving error

```
neither a main nor it is a servlet specified in web.xml
```

Here is my servlet class code..

```
public  class Service extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            BLC blc = new BLC();
            blc.captureCDRProcess();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
  } 
}
```

And here is my Web.xml Code..

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pojoserv.Service</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Service</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Don't _run the servlet_. Run your application on a servlet container.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my this application has one servlet file and one POJO class .On deploying it to Apache tomcat it is showing HTTP status 404

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is it possible to deploy this applications .war file on tomcat

Comment: Look in (tomcat home)/logs/catalina.out for any exceptions

Comment: make sure that your `Service` servlet class is in `pojoserv` package